# Execute Javascript inside XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing an Ajax-script that should load content dynamically. I've been using jQuery for the longest time to achieve this (which worked fine), yet I want to go back to just vanilla JS for certain reasons.

In jQuery I used:

```
function load(url) {
  $.get(url).done(function(data) {
    $('dynamic-content').html(data);
  })

  $("a[dyn]").on("click", function() {
      load("/test.php");
  });
}
```

**Test.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello");</script>
<a dyn>Load from here</a>
```

Which would load the page into the "dynamic-content" element and executes the alert after you clicked on an a-element with the "dyn" attribute. And you could use the "Load from here" button.

**Vanilla JS:**

```
   function load(url) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {}
        httpRequest.open('GET', url, false);
        httpRequest.send();

        var ajax_content_container = document.querySelector('dynamic');

        ajax_content_container.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;

    };

    document.querySelectorAll('a[dyn]').forEach(type_Accelerated_Trigger => {
       type_Accelerated_Trigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          load("/test.php");
       }, false);
    });
```

Now the problem is; since I went back to vanilla-JS, the file (test.php) loads, but the code will simply not execute. I've tried eval to solve this problem, which works, yet it's not very secure and requires you to manually select every script. The "Load from here" button would also *not work*, since Javascript only performs the "`foreach`" check when you load the parent page.

How would I be able to execute the could from the "test.php" file when you click the "Load from here" button and how can I use the "Load from here" button which is included in the "test.php" response?

Solutions I already tried:

- eval the Vanilla JS code from "test.php". It works, yet with jQuery, you only have to load the script once and it reads all elements in the response.

(Note: the actual code I use is better and also works, it's just that I don't know what the best approach is in this case. I'm also sorry if this question is unclear, I really don't know how I should explain this.)

Comment: Have you tried using `[...]` or `Array.from` on your elements, as in `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[dyn]')).forEach...`? And are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @ZacAnger I've not used Array.from. Yet it also doesn't display any errors. It works fine as long as all the "buttons" are located in the parent file. I've even turned off the async option.

Comment: Also you might not be aware, but using XHR like that is no longer necessary unless you need to support Internet Explorer. Fetch is the norm now: `const load = (uri, target) => window.fetch(uri).then((res) => res.text()).then(text => { target.innerHTML = text }).catch(err => { console.error(err) }) `

Comment: @ZacAnger Interesting! I've seen a thing or two about Fetch. I can try that.

Comment: @ZacAnger The main problem with Fetch is that it doesn't send unique headers. So in PHP, you can differ a normal request from a XHR request. So I'm afraid I have to stick with XHR.

Comment: You can actually set whatever headers you want in fetch :). The `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest` convention with XHR isn't really unique, it's just a non-standard convention that got popular. `fetch(uri, { headers: { 'x-requested-with': 'fetch' ...` for example. That's not really related to the issue you have right now, since your request works fine, though.

Comment: @ZacAnger Thanks for clarifying that. It's definitely worth to move over to Fetch. I've looked further into the problem and I really think that it's the "forEach" function causing the problem. I can access the function from the XHR-response, yet the element is just not selectable since it's a new request.